# Can't install this Python module (IMDbPY) because of El Capitan? (Deprecation?)

Tags: python, pip, imdbpy

So I'm trying to install [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/support.html) with pip, but I'm getting the following warning in yellow font, followed by a bunch of warnings in red.

I've tried several commands to solve this and without luck. I've search for the warning in yellow (that starts with DEPRECATION) and have found a thread on Github detailing some changes with OS X El-Capitan and how the "six" package is affected, and I managed to install it independently, but it seems like IMDbPY still wants to uninstall for some reason?

```
Installing collected packages: six, sqlparse, decorator, Tempita, sqlalchemy-migrate, IMDbPY
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 315, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-QNP1Pr-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It needs a different version of six, I'd create a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and install whatever you need in there.

Comment: Have you tried using sudo with pip?

Answer (score 0):

From anyone who is still interested on this, you can **install it from source** without any errors.

Pip or easy_install didn't work for me either on El Capitan *(at least when I installed it)*.

You can get the latest zip package on http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/downloads.html#source-code.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
pip install --user imdbpy
```

it will work. Did for me anyway.